# get all elements in class

Tags: php, class, dom

I want to use PHP DOM to get all elements in a particular class.

My HTML

```
<tr>
  <td><ul class="up">
      <li><a href="/updown.html#ud1">Russia</a></li>
      <li><a href="/updown.html#ud2">Pakistan</a></li>
          <li><a href="/updown.html#ud3">Iran</a></li>
    </ul></td>
</tr>

<tr>

  <td valign="top"><ul class="down">
      <li><a href="/updown.html#ud4">Spain</a></li>
      <li><a href="/updown.html#ud5">France</a></li>
    </ul></td>
</tr>
```

Why won't this PHP work?

```
$elements = $xpath->query('//ul[@class="up"]'); 
$elements = $elements->getElementsByTagName('li');
```

Comment: Use XPath : http://php.net/manual/de/class.domxpath.php

Comment: What is the rest of you `php dom` script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try -

```
....

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);                     
$nodes = $xpath->query('//ul[@class="up"]'); 

foreach($nodes as $node) {                      

    foreach($node->getElementsByTagName('li') as $li) {

    ....  // li elements of ul with class="up"

    }
}
```

---

So using the following code -

```
<?php 
$str = '
<table>
<tr>
  <td><ul class="up">
      <li><a href="/updown.html#ud1">Russia</a></li>
      <li><a href="/updown.html#ud2">Pakistan</a></li>
      <li><a href="/updown.html#ud3">Iran</a></li>
    </ul></td>
</tr>

<tr>

  <td valign="top"><ul class="down">
      <li><a href="/updown.html#ud4">Spain</a></li>
      <li><a href="/updown.html#ud5">France</a></li>
    </ul></td>
</tr>
</table>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadHTML($str);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);                     
$nodes = $xpath->query('//ul[@class="up"]');   // get <ul>'s with class 'up'
foreach($nodes as $node) {                      // loops through each <ul>
    foreach($node->getElementsByTagName('li') as $li) {    // loops through the <li>'s

    echo $li->nodeValue . "<br/>\n";   // echo's the <li> elements

}}

?>
```

The output is -

```
Russia
Pakistan
Iran
```

Comment: thanks, however, I tried a different way to get the li elements, and it's not working. I updated my original question

Comment: Not really sure what you are looking to do. I have updated my answer with a full script that echo's the `<li>` elements that are in the a `<ul>` with `class="up"`